# Question (?) mark in telegram markdown v2 url fails

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

in the telegram v2 markdown language there's no details on question marks "?".  A URL like the below breaks at the question mark and putting a "" before the question mark doesn't do anything.   Any ideas?

```
[bog](https://bogged.finance/swap?tokenIn=BNB&tokenOut=0xe2e6e66551E5062Acd56925B48bBa981696CcCC2)
```

In the app the URL that comes through is `https://bogged.finance/swap` so everything after the ? in the URL is getting truncated.

Answer (score 0):

this is a UI bug.  The links still work:
https://bugs.telegram.org/c/5545